# "vim ~/.zshrc" for installment of flutter SDK

Tags: vim, zsh, zshrc, flutter

I want to download the flutter SDK and need to open the file "zshrc". this is necessary to set up the flutter SDK. As i found out "zshrc" doesn’t exist by default in Mac OS. Everytime I try to run vim ~/.zshrc it tells me that there is no such file or directory called "zshrc". What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vim` does, like any decent text editor, create a non-existing file for you. Hence, this looks like a vim problem, unless, of course, your shell is something like `sh` or `dash`, in which the tilde in `~/.zshrc` does not make sense. Hence I would, before starting vim, verify the current shell: Before running `vim`, enter a single, closing parenthese on the command line:

```
)
```

and look at the error message. The error message will tell you, which shell you are running.

Comment: thx for your answer. it helped me out, I just forgot to comment...

Answer (score 0):

Just create that file yourself:

```
touch ~/.zshrc
```

PS: AFAIR, zsh automatically creates these files on its first run. Are you sure your default shell is zsh?